# What C# Datagridview event will update column immediately after an operation

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am multiplying 2 cells in my datagridview, to display it on a third column, I want the results on the third cell to be done as am editing the fields on either the first or second cell.

I am using - `private void DataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)`
but this will only update, when i click on another cell in the datagrid.

I need an event suggestion that will deliver it as it's done on MSExcel

Comment: `DataGridView.CellValueChanged` [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged?view=netframework-4.8]

Comment: Have you considered making a `DataTable` from your data and then add an `Expression` column to the table to do the multiplication? Something like `multiplyColumn.Expression = “col1 * col2”;` MS: [DataColumn.Expression Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: none of this worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `private void DataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)`and it worked fine. Thank You.

Comment: The answer I posted recalculates the answer as you type each number in the cell.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DgvMultiplyTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void CalculateAnswer()
        {
            int dgvRow = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
            int dgvColumn = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
            int firstNumber = 0;
            int secondNumber = 0;
            int answer = 0;


            if (dataGridView1.Rows[dgvRow].Cells[0].EditedFormattedValue != null &&
               dataGridView1.Rows[dgvRow].Cells[1].EditedFormattedValue != null)
            {
                if ((int.TryParse(dataGridView1.Rows[dgvRow].Cells[0].EditedFormattedValue.ToString(), out firstNumber) == true) &&
                     (int.TryParse(dataGridView1.Rows[dgvRow].Cells[1].EditedFormattedValue.ToString(), out secondNumber) == true))
                {
                    answer = firstNumber * secondNumber;
                    dataGridView1.Rows[dgvRow].Cells[2].Value = answer;
                }
            }
        }

        private void DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Control.KeyUp -= new KeyEventHandler(Control_KeyUp);
            e.Control.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(Control_KeyUp);
        }

        private void Control_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            CalculateAnswer();
            dataGridView1.Invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```